# @annotation error while launching application with Tomcat 6 server

Tags: tomcat, gradle, intellij-idea, aspectj

Facing below exception while launching application with Tomcat 6 server
In tomcat configuration Java version is set to 1.8
In IntelliJ Project settings also Java version is set to 1.8
However when i open PoincutParser.class file , I see below message
[PointcutParser issue](https://i.stack.imgur.com/6qlJx.png)

```
Caused by: java.lang.IllegalArgumentException: error the @annotation pointcut expression is only supported at Java 5 compliance level or above
    at org.aspectj.weaver.tools.PointcutParser.parsePointcutExpression(PointcutParser.java:315)
    at org.springframework.aop.aspectj.AspectJExpressionPointcut.buildPointcutExpression(AspectJExpressionPointcut.java:195)
    at org.springframework.aop.aspectj.AspectJExpressionPointcut.checkReadyToMatch(AspectJExpressionPointcut.java:181)
    at org.springframework.aop.aspectj.AspectJExpressionPointcut.getClassFilter(AspectJExpressionPointcut.java:162)
    at org.springframework.aop.support.AopUtils.canApply(AopUtils.java:200)
    at org.springframework.aop.support.AopUtils.canApply(AopUtils.java:254)
    at org.springframework.aop.support.AopUtils.findAdvisorsThatCanApply(AopUtils.java:286)
    at org.springframework.aop.framework.autoproxy.AbstractAdvisorAutoProxyCreator.findAdvisorsThatCanApply(AbstractAdvisorAutoProxyCreator.java:117)
    at org.springframework.aop.framework.autoproxy.AbstractAdvisorAutoProxyCreator.findEligibleAdvisors(AbstractAdvisorAutoProxyCreator.java:87)
    at org.springframework.aop.framework.autoproxy.AbstractAdvisorAutoProxyCreator.getAdvicesAndAdvisorsForBean(AbstractAdvisorAutoProxyCreator.java:68)
    at org.springframework.aop.framework.autoproxy.AbstractAutoProxyCreator.wrapIfNecessary(AbstractAutoProxyCreator.java:359)
    at org.springframework.aop.framework.autoproxy.AbstractAutoProxyCreator.postProcessAfterInitialization(AbstractAutoProxyCreator.java:322)
    at org.springframework.beans.factory.support.AbstractAutowireCapableBeanFactory.applyBeanPostProcessorsAfterInitialization(AbstractAutowireCapableBeanFactory.java:407)
    at org.springframework.beans.factory.support.AbstractAutowireCapableBeanFactory.initializeBean(AbstractAutowireCapableBeanFactory.java:1426)
    at org.springframework.beans.factory.support.AbstractAutowireCapableBeanFactory.doCreateBean(AbstractAutowireCapableBeanFactory.java:519)
    ... 74 more code here
```

Answer (score 0):

Check your transitive dependencies for old versions of AspectJ.